# HTML: how to indicate questions with radioboxes as answers in proper way?

Tags: html, seo, radio-button, accessibility

I have a question in HTML form and radioboxes as answers, like this:

```
<span>What is your favorite fruit?</span>
<input type="radio" name="favFruit" id="banana"><label for="banana">Banana</label>
<input type="radio" name="favFruit" id="orange"><label for="orange">Orange</label>
```

But I realised, that question is not connected with answers, which is probably bad for SEO, accessibility and and could be bad for future maintenance of application. So I added `aria-describedby` attribute:

```
<span id="favFruitQuestion">What is your favorite fruit?</span>
<input type="radio" name="favFruit" id="banana" aria-describedby="favFruitQuestion">
    <label for="banana">Banana</label>
<input type="radio" name="favFruit" id="orange" aria-describedby="favFruitQuestion">
    <label for="orange">Orange</label>
```

But at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) I found article [How to structure an HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form#The_%3Cfieldset%3E_and_%3Clegend%3E_elements), when advice is to wrap answers in `fieldset` tag ans put question in `legend` tag:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>What is your favourite fruit?</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="favFruit" id="banana"><label for="banana">Banana</label>
    <input type="radio" name="favFruit" id="orange"><label for="orange">Orange</label>
</fieldset>
```

But it could not be trustworthy at 100%, because, because there is written:

> This article is in need of a technical review.

Is it really a best way to indicate a question with radioboxes as answers? If it's not, what is the best way? Thank you in advance for every answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `<legend>` / `<fieldset>` is the correct tool to use.

Avoid overlong legends though. Some screen readers will read out the entire legend before each label.

Comment: WCAG 2.0 [H71: Providing a description for groups of form controls using fieldset and legend elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H71.html)